# Guys i am getting error as below while copying the file from puppet master to agents

Tags: file-copying

1.when i used "puppet agent -t" command in agents it's not retrieving from puppet server and getting the error as below.
2.the below code i have used in modules path:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mailx/manifests/init.pp and i  have included this class in site.pp file as below.

Error: 1.I

> /Stage[main]/Mailx/File[/etc/mail.rc]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/mailx/mail.rc

file { '/etc/mail.rc':

ensure => present,

mode   => '0644',

owner  => 'root',

group  => 'root',

source => 'puppet:///modules/mailx/mail.rc',
}

node 'default', {
include mailx
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be much easier to read if you present it like this.

```
#/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/init.pp
class mailx {
  file { '/etc/mail.rc':
    ensure => present,
    mode   => '0644',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/mailx/mail.rc',
  }
}
```

And then the file

```
#/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mailx/files/mail.rc
set smtp=your.smtp.server
set from="from email address"
```

The module should be in
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mailx/manifests/init.pp
Notice the "production" after the environments.
It may have just been a typo when you put the path in to here but you spelt puppetlabs as puppelabc.

And the file should be here
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mailx/files/mail.rc

Each directory under the environment directory is an environment and that error says Puppet is looking in the production environment for that file.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your response, I have  created all the modules under the environments only and the file location will be under the below path,   path:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mailx/files/mail.rc                                       I have followed same path as you mentioned above even i am getting same error

Comment: I've added a bit more to the example. It might be worth checking the fileserver.conf settings, details here https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/file_serving.html#creating-a-new-mount-point-in-fileserver.conf but if it's a default install it should be ok.